# MySQL error, can no longer login as root

Tags: linux, terminal, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So I updated my MySQL and PHPMyAdmin yesterday and ever since then I cannot login to MySQL as root or any other username I have. I tried both phpmyadmin and the terminal and still cannot get in. How do I reset the password?[image: Terminal]

[image]

Comment: Your server is down. Start it.

Comment: It's not down. I'm able to access the web interface of the server (it's a Synology server) and I can ssh into it too.

Comment: you either need to reboot the machine to start the service automatically or go to the services snapin, or start with the cmd prompt if you can get to them.  otherwise you need to contact your administrator (if that's you, youre up the creek without a paddle)

Comment: your mysql server, not your web server or ssh daemon

Comment: Tried `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` and `service mysqld restart` both did not work, any other ways to restart from terminal you can recommend?

Comment: You should probably check your `mysqld` logs (probably in `/var/log/mysql`) to see what's stopping it from starting

Comment: oh man, there's no mysqld log in `/var/log/mysql`. Also @Simon I'm up poop creek here in that case.

Comment: Can you try starting it by hand, like running `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` by hand, or trying to reconstruct the command line from `/etc/init.d/mysqld` to run it and see if you get errors that way?

Comment: Just typing in "mysqld" on its own gives this:
`160621 11:45:31 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49-MariaDB) starting as process 16974 ...`
`160621 11:45:31 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!`

`160621 11:45:31 [ERROR] Aborting`

    `160621 11:45:31 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete`

Comment: Ok, isolated the problem somewhat. A co-worker just told me they tried to import a db over the weekend via a script and was logged in as root; the import failed part of the way through due to her machine being on wifi and lost access to the db. Now they are also unable to login with the same error message. Don't know if this related to the current problem.

Comment: Ok, I managed to restart the mysql, but got another error as it was taking a while to shutdown: `ERROR! Failed to stop running server, so refusing to try to start.`

Any ideas on what to try next? I'll be googling around in the meantime. Thanks for the help so far everyone.

Comment: Talked to a support team. They will be going through debug logs to see what broke the login access. They also asked if I could get a log of the user's shell commands when they ssh'd up to the server to import the DB to isolate the problem. It's not built-in, according to this:  https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/logging-every-shell-command/

Comment: which version of `mysql` & `OS` are you having ?

Comment: @Mongrel MySQL version 5.5.49-0065, OS is x64 Linux, specifically x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_cedarview_1813+

Comment: Update: I will need to uninstall/reinstall MySQL to fix this. Do my databases also get deleted in the process?

Comment: no your database will not get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to regain root access via phpMyAdmin using the following command in the terminal

`killall -9 mysqld`

Followed by restarting the web service for this particular server. That seemed to fix the problem.